# Add Database: Operating System Error, The process cannot access file b/c it is being used by another process)

Tags: c#, database-connection, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm having problems adding a SQL database file in my C# Windows application.

I'm using the Entity Data Model Wizard in Visual Studios 2010 Express to connect to the following MS SQL database file: 
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\School.mdf

When I click "Ok" to connect, I get the following error: Operating System Error 32 (The process cannot access file b/c it is being used by another process).

I'm running MSSQL Server 2008 R2 (not Express), and have changed the connection string to "Data Source = ." and "User Instance = False". (MSSQL Server 2008 doesn't support User Instances.)

I can open the School.mdf database in SQL Server Management Studio, but I get the same error when I try to sp_attach_db School.mdf to master.

Changing SQL Server to run under Local System didn't solve the problem. There is full read/write permission to the database files.

There are no other applications running on my computer when I attempt to connect to this database -- not even SQL Server Management Studio, and per the task manager, there is only one instance of sqlservr.exe running on the machine.

Thanks in advance for any thoughts. -David

Comment: Not sure what the connection string has to do with a file sharing violation error.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the error message? Obviously, someone is holding that file open so SQL Server cannot access it.

Find out what is holding it open using Sysinternals Process Explorer.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  After running process explorer, the only other process connected with this file is the SQL Server (sqlservr.exe), which is running as a service.  So the question is how to let another connection access this file when User Interface = False?  Thanks.

Comment: Restart SQL Server and attach the database as a normal database. Then, make your connection string point to that database by name, not by path.